# Displaying SVG in HTML page using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, svg

I have an SVG image as a part of the XML file which I want to display on my HTML page using XSLT conversion.
I tried using the IMG tag but the image does not show up.

My XML file segment containing SVG:

```
<topimagebase64>url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABUAAAAJACAYAAABMocy1AAAAIGNIUk0AAHomAACAhAAA+gAAAIDo&#13;
AAB1MAAA6mAAADqYAAAXcJy6UTwAAAAEZ0FNQQAAsY58+1GTAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAZiS0dE&#13;
AP8A/wD/oL2nkwAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAIABJREFUeNrs3Q+oXeWdL/wVJ1AvDTS+&#13;
zb11mFz0XlOMXEsjWlSqNKLepBgxUqUpV6mSSAwq6quiQUUlFVscUVFRsaKlioq5VNHSSJQoOuhQ&#13;
................ 
')</topimagebase64>
```

(cannot post the entire text due to space restrictions)

My XSLT:

```
<img src= "//topimagebase64" width="30% " margin-top="20px" margin-left="10px"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Saumya Govil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url('data:...)` is not an ordinary SVG image, it's a [Data URI](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/), i.e. simply binary data. But if you don't want to use CSS but the `img` element, you need to strip the `url()` wrapper. The following XSLT 1.0 transform...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <img src="{ substring( normalize-space(//topimagebase64), 5, string-length(//topimagebase64)-5)}" />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...works on this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <topimagebase64>url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7)</topimagebase64>
</root>
```

Alternatively, use CSS:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <style>
                    div {
                        background: <xsl:value-of select="//topimagebase64" />;
                        width: 500px;
                        height: 500px;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>

                <div></div>

            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you use `substring()` with fixed indexes, I suggest working with `translate(normalize-space(topimagebase64), ' ', '')` to make sure you cut out the right portion, regardless of the input string layout.